# Write correlation handler event to the AppFabric

Tags: logging, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I'm implementing a WF4 service. I want to see the correlation Id of my workflow instance in app-fabric event log. Basicaly I want to write custom message to app fabric.  So far I have used this code but no results,

```
protected override Contract1 Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
{
         //...........
           CustomTrackingRecord record=new CustomTrackingRecord(context.WorkflowInstanceId,"test      record...",TraceLevel.Info);
           context.Track(record);    
        //..........         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able accomplish  my requirement by configuring tracking profile. In tricking profile I have added tracking variables. Here is how I did it.

```
            <activitystatequery activityname="Process New Order">
                <states>
                  <state name="Closed">
                </state></states>
                <variables>
                  <variable name="StatusText">
                  <variable name="NewPurchaseOrder">
                  <variable name="PurchaseTotal">

                </variable></variable></variable></variables>
              </activitystatequery>
```

More details about the implimntation. http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2012/02/workflow-foundation-4-app-fabric.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet the code here is emitting tracking just fine, but you'll need to configure AppFabric to be a tracking participant to pick those up.